# iPhone - Place DRRoundSwitch programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, storyboard

My app is reading a JSON code and putting a question in a cell.
I would like to place  [DRRoundSwitch](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch) for Yes/No question, but could not find any way to place it programmatically.
Is is possible to do it or I have to use on/off for yes/no questions?

Comment: Why can't you place it programmatically? You should be able to just include the source files in your project, then `[[DRRoundSwitch alloc] init]` should work.

Comment: I've done it like this but doesn't work:DCRoundSwitch *ynSwitch = [[DCRoundSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220,150,0,0)] ;    
    [self.view addSubview:ynSwitch];

Comment: Thanks I"ve got it eventually...I put "0, 0" for width and height so it wasn't visible. Thanks it was a good hint.

Comment: I've done that a few times myself. I really wish Xcode would give a warning about assigning zero-sized rects to views.